# Set picklist to null with Javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a picklist and I'm trying to set the value to --None-- with Javascript on press of a button.

**Visualforce:**

```
<apex:commandbutton onclick="clearFields(); return false;" value="clear"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!App_Components__c.Product__c}" style="width:290px" id="product"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
    function clearFields(){
//NONE APPEAR TO WORK
        document.getElementById('product').value ="--None--";
        document.getElementById('product').value ="";
        document.getElementById('product').value =null;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visualforce element `id` attributes are prefixed. You need to use a different selector. For instance, an "ends with" selector (`$=`) would work:

```
var element = document.querySelector("[id$='product']");
```

See also:

- [Best Practices for Accessing Component IDs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm)
- [$Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_component.htm?search_text=$component)
- [Using $Component to Reference Components from JavaScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_access.htm?search_text=$component)

Answer (score 1):

The `inputfield` does not turn directly into a `select`

You can use the `$Component` syntax to access the top level `inputField` tag, but then you may need to traverse the inner elements of this tag.

To set an option on the `select` once you have identified it, do something like this:

```
var selectElement = yourSelectElementThatYouObtainedEarlier
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = "--None--";
selectElement.add(option,0);
```